# SUN RPC: Does the server satisfy requests one by one?

Tags: rpc

I am new to SunRPC. I would like to know what the server will do if multiple clients send requests to the server concurrently. Will the server queue the requests and reply one by one. Or will it respond parallelly? Because i remember reading somewhere that it can respond parallelly.

Btw, I am talking about a simple single threaded server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends upon the server in question. It's possible to write servers to work in both fashions. At least the stereotypical Sun RPC server, NFSd, is usually written with the intention of supporting hundreds or thousands of clients simultaneously -- a file server that serves files to one client at a time is pretty useless. But the server is simplified because the NFS protocol is (mostly) stateless -- each request stands on its own. (Newer NFS protocol versions are less stateless and complicate both servers and clients significantly.)

If the server is *very* simple, you can probably start it with `inetd(8)`, the Internet super-server, which will run configurable servers when connections arrive at configurable ports. `inetd(8)` was much more common back in the days when even swap space was at a premium and it made sense to execute new programs on every client connect. The bonus is each server is independent of the other servers -- each one is spawned in its own `fork(2)`ed process -- and only use of shared data would require extra programming effort.